How to calculate the number of different tiles in a tessellation?
For example, in the $4.8.8$ tiling, are there roughly as many octagons as squares? How would I find that out for an arbitrary tiling? 
Edit: Ok yes, obviously there are infinitely many of each. What I mean is for any arbitrary section of that infinite tiling, what is the ratio of tiles? Obviously it won't be the same for exactly every section but I assume there would some kind of rough ratio.

It is not at all clear what you are asking. For instance, as I would think that the literal answer to your question is Yes, because there are infinitely many octagons and infinitely many squares... but then I would guess that this answer would not be satisfactory to you. I suggest you hit the edit button and clarify what you are asking.

If the tiling is periodic, then you should find a fundamental domain of that tiling. A fundamental domain is a patch of tiles $\mathcal{P} = \{T_1, \ldots, T_k\}$ so that there exists a full-rank lattice $L\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ such that

$\bigcup_{t \in L} \mathcal{P}+t = \mathbb{R}^d$ (periodically covers), and
for all $t,t'\in L$, if $(\mathcal{P}+t) \cap (\mathcal{P}+t') \neq \emptyset$, then $t=t'$ (no non-trivial overlaps).

The frequency of tiles in a fundamental domain will then be the asymptotic frequency for large patches of your tiling. That is, for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists an $R>0$ so that all patches (that are not too weird) with radius at least $R$ will have frequencies within epsilon of the frequencies of tiles in a fundamental domain.
